# How I can Send confirmation email on new customer registration in my asp.net project?

Tags: asp.net, email, registration, send, confirmation

I have my aps.net project and I want to add "Send confirmation email on new customer registration" feature on my website.

what should I have do and how?
*I don't know anything about.. so look at me as **kid** ^_^.LOL!!*

Answer (score 1):

When new customer join your site you need to create unique for each customer then make url which is check this token is in your database or not if it is in database it is valid user if not it is not valid token or valid customer.

You need to send this token to mail of joined customer's email address. using following code.

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.MyWebsiteDomainName.com", 25);

smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@MyWebsiteDomainName.com", "myIDPassword");
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

//Setting From , To and CC
mail.From = new MailAddress("info@MyWebsiteDomainName", "MyWeb Site");
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("info@MyWebsiteDomainName"));
mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress("MyEmailID@gmail.com"));

smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

You need to send one link in email like below.

```
http://yoursite.com/confirmation.aspx?token=<UNIQUE-TOKEN-GOES-HERE>
```

If email of customer is valid then email is goes otherwise email is not receive on dummy email. if customer receive email inside email have one link where customer need to click when customer click on link they redirect to your site then you check token is valid or not.

Comment: Thanks dear **Paresh** I'll try it :*